# Magento 2 get request parametes in graphql

Tags: magento2, graphql

I want all the applied filters in graphql aggregation

Can we use $this-getRequest() in graphql

I am getting blank array in $args

Any help would be Appreciated!

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/330488/how-do-i-capture-graphql-post-data

Answer (score 0):

You can use below class to get requested data
\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface